# Why doesn't the curly braces work for a Vue app within a Django template?

Tags: django, vue.js, vue-component

Basically, Im trying to integrate Vue with Django. I have the following template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Django Vue</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        {% verbatim %}
            <div id="components-demo">
                <button-counter></button-counter>
            </div>
        {% endverbatim %}

        <!-- Vuejs -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

        <!-- App -->
        <script>

            // Define a new component called button-counter
            Vue.component('button-counter', {
              data: function () {
                return {
                  count: 0
                }
              },
              template: `
                    <button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>
                `
            });

            // App definition
            new Vue({ el: '#components-demo' });
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Everything is very simple, CDNs are used, not webpack. The component shows up, but the count does not. In other words, the curly braces are not functioning properly within my template. Why is that? I have the verbatim tag up and running.

It looks like this:
[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didnt wrap the `{{count}}` with a `{% verbatim %}` tag, which means `{{count}}` is being interpreted by Django, not by Vue (you should be able to see that this is the case if you inspect the template that is being rendered).

This should work:

```
<!-- App -->
{% verbatim %}
<script>
// Define a new component called button-counter
Vue.component('button-counter', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },
    template: `
        <button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>
    `
    });

    // App definition
    new Vue({ el: '#components-demo' });
</script>
{% endverbatim %}
```

The `{% verbatim %}` tag you used is not really necessary, because the reason you want to use it (in this case) is because both Django and Vue use the same mustache `{{}}` syntax, which is causing the conflict. This means you should use `{% verbatim %}` only if there would otherwise be a conflict of syntax (for example, the mustache syntax).